# What is a good way to handle an Optional<User> object returned by a Spring Data JPA repository in a situation like this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot application. Into a service class I have this service method:

```
@Override
public User getUserById(Integer userId) {
    Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
    return retrievedUser.get();
}
```

As usual it is calling the Spring Data JPA **findById()** method returning an **Optional** object.

I am returning the **User** object. And here I have the following doubt: if the **Optional** is **empty**, it is throwing an exception when I this operation is performed:

```
retrievedUser.get()
```

So now...what is the most common way to handle situation like this when I have a **Optional** object.

The previous service method is called into a controller method implementing an API, this one:

```
@ApiOperation(
          value = "Retrieve an user by its id", 
          notes = "",
          produces = "application/json")
@GetMapping(value = "/{useridOrEmail}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByIdOrEmail(@PathVariable("useridOrEmail") String userIdOrEmail,
                                        @RequestParam(value="isEmail", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean isEmail) 
                            throws NotFoundException  {
    
    log.info(String.format("****** Retrieve the user having ID or email: %s *******", userIdOrEmail));
    
    User retrievedUser = null;
    
    if(!isEmail)
        retrievedUser = this.userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(userIdOrEmail));
    else
        retrievedUser = this.userService.getUserByemail(userIdOrEmail);
    
    if (retrievedUser == null) {
        String ErrMsg = String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userIdOrEmail);
        
        log.warning(ErrMsg);
        
        throw new NotFoundException(ErrMsg);
    }
        
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(retrievedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        
}
```

As you can see in my controller method I am checking if the result of the previous service is null, in case an exception will be thrown. This exception is handled by a class extenging **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** in such a way to create a proper response.

So my idea was change my service method putting this **retrievedUser.get()** operation into a **try catch**. If I obtain the exception my **getUserById()** service method will return **null** and so my controller method will thrown the **NotFoundException** exception that will be handled returning a specific error response by Spring.

Could be a good solution or exist better way to handle situation like this?

Comment: If you already have an exception handler for specific type of exception, then I think its okay to translate NoSuchElementException to what-ever-type you are using. Even though not big fun of this approach, but in java I can't see anything else that can be done.

Comment: Why not return the `Optional` from service and then `this.userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(userIdOrEmail)).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userIdOrEmail)))`?

Comment: Why not simply put `orElseThrow` in _the service_ that is responsible for the business logic?

Comment: "*So my idea was change my service method putting this retrievedUser.get() operation into a try catch.*" - Or even simpler: use [`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)). I agree that moving the logic of throwing the `Exception` should be part of the service method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would return Optionals from the service then you could chain them real nicely like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByIdOrEmail(@PathVariable("useridOrEmail") String userIdOrEmail,
                                        @RequestParam(value="isEmail", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean isEmail) 
                            throws NotFoundException  {
    
    log.info(String.format("****** Retrieve the user having ID or email: %s *******", userIdOrEmail));
    return fetchUser(userIdOrEmail, isEmail)
           .map((user) -> new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK))
           .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userIdOrEmail)));
}

private Optional<User> fetchUser(String idOrEmail, boolean isEmail) {
    return isEmail 
           ? this.userService.getUserByemail(idOrEmail)
           : this.userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(idOrEmail));
}
```

And logging the warning should be handled in a common exception handler which logs all the Not Found's similar way.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to **accept** whatever the database returns. Then the controller **should decide** what to do:

```java
Optional<User> retrievedUser = isEmail
   ? this.userService.getUserByemail(userIdOrEmail)
   : this.userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(userIdOrEmail));
    
if (!retrievedUser.isPresent()) {
   String ErrMsg = String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userIdOrEmail);
   log.warning(ErrMsg);
   throw new NotFoundException(ErrMsg);
}

return new ResponseEntity<User>(retrievedUser.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
```